# App fails to connect to running laravel-websockets instance when started with supervisor

Tags: laravel-websockets

This was working in the past...not sure why it doesn't now.

If I start laravel-websockets on the command-line, my app connects fine.  If I start it with supervisor, my app can't connect.  It's listening on the same address and port.

Any ideas where I should look?

Thanks